# Sort dictionary by key: single key priority and alphabetical

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary `d`:

```py
d = { 
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4,
}
```

I want to sort this such that:

1. The key with value `x` is first.
2. Everything else is sorted alphabetically.

So if `x = 'c'` then I want the output to be:

```py
>>> print(new_d)
>>> { 'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Is there a straightforward / easy / Pythonic way to do this? And yes I have seen and understand the plethora of answers for the questions [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) and [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: What did you find unsatisfactory about the answers in the two questions you linked? Or what further information are you looking for?

Comment: I don't know how to sort on this condition! I don't even know how to do it with a lambda...

Comment: (If it is that easy can you answer it? :-) )

Comment: The top answer in the first question you linked to is very clear in explaining that you can't sort a dictionary. If you are using Python 3.6+, you can create a new `dict` that will be ordered by insertion order. Or you could use the `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries pre Python 3.7 are not sorted, however, you can sort the list of tuples garnered from `dict.items`, and if you are using Python 3.7, create a `dict` from the result. The `lambda` sort key returns a list with two elements. The first element is the result of the key comparison, in this case, `x == 'c'`, while the second element is the numerical value associated with the key:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4} 
x = 'c'
new_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda c:[c[0] != x, c[-1]])
```

Output:

```
[('c', 3), ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 4)]
```

In Python 3.7:

```
print(dict(new_d))
```

Output:

```
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```